# Draw phase plane in $(x,y)$-plane given system of differential equations in polar coordinates

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, polar-coordinates

Given $
\begin{cases}
 \frac{dr}{dt} = r(1-r),\\
 \frac{d\varphi}{dt} = \sin^2\varphi + (1-r)^3,
\end{cases}$
I want to draw the phase plane in the $(x,y)$-coordinate system with $x=r\cos(\varphi)$ and $y=r\sin(\varphi)$.
I looked at questions that did it the other way round but I don't see how to apply that to this version. I tried substituting $r=\frac{x}{\cos(\varphi)}$ and $r=\frac{y}{\cos(\varphi)}$, but I didn't know where to go from there.

I determined that the stationary points (so both derivatives equal to zero) are $(1,0)$ and $(1,\pi)$ in the $(r,\varphi)$-plane, and therefore $(1,0)$ and $(-1, 0)$ in the $(x,y)$-plane.

I also have a phase plane for the $(r,\varphi)$ plane (in which I drew a few trajectories to check that the stationary points were correct), note that $p=\varphi$ here.

[image: Phase plane in the (r,φ)-plane]

Comment: @Moo Thank you. This gives me expressions for $dx$ and $dy$ in terms of $x$, $y$, $r$, $dr$ and $d\varphi$. Because $r=\sqrt(x^2+y^2)$ that is not a problem, $dr=r(1-r)$, and I just wrote $r$ in terms of $x$ and $y$, so that's also not a problem, but how do I write $d\varphi$ in terms of $x$ and $y$?

I have that $d\varphi=sin^2(\varphi) + (1-r)^3$, and I don't know how to write $\varphi$ in terms of $x$ and $y$.

Without doing that conversion I cannot use my program PPlane to plot the phase plane, because it requires differential equations of the form $\dot{x}=f(x,y)$ and $\dot{y}=g(x,y)$

Comment: I used that $\varphi=\text{acos}(\frac{x}{r})$ and this gave me the following phase plane: https://gyazo.com/af4a4d154d850f313b4a5fb62360bf6d. It looks okay, but I do not know how to check if it's okay

Comment: @Moo to my not perfect eyes using $\varphi=\text{arctan}(\frac{y}{x})$ gives the same phase plane as using $\varphi=\text{acos}(\frac{x}{r})$, (See here: https://gyazo.com/b96a41d09bfa895dd25ea61a56e8adc0), so I think I don't understand you.

Comment: Yes that's clear. So then I have to differential equations $dx$ and $dy$ only in terms of $x$ and $y$ and that way I can find the phase plane in the $(x,y)$-plane.

Comment: @Moo There's still one thing unclear, can I just replace $d\varphi$ with $\sin^2(\varphi) + (1-r)^3$ which is equal to $\frac{d\varphi}{dt}$ in the original problem (and the same for $dr$), so that I get $dx$ and $dy$ in terms of only $x$ and $y$ without differential operators on the right hand side of the equal sign of $dx=$ and $dy=$?